# JavaScript waiting until facebook button loads

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a facebook button on my site (implemented through XFBML and their JS SDK), and I need to dynamically position it based on it's size (I have to find out it's width / height).

The problem is, window.load doesn't work for this because the button is loaded asynchronously (I think this is the reason). The button ends up in the wrong place because of this (JS gets the height / width at the wrong stage of it's rendering).

How do I go about calling a function only after the facebook button is rendered?

Comment: What button? Doesn't it have its own events?

Comment: The subscribe button - I'm not sure if it has a 'on load' event.

Comment: It has  `xfbml.render` event: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: Ahh thank you - You can post that as the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `xfbml.rende` which is called after widget is rendered: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/